# Google Sites URL termination?

Tags: url, google-classic-sites

I made a Google Site on the wrong Google Account, so I deleted the site and permanently deleted it the deleted sites folder. I switched to another account and tried to create the site al over, but it wouldnt let me. It said

> Cannot create site in destination domain

at the top. The sites URL was:

> https://sites.google.com/site/itsover9000

It doesn't seem to be taken, as the site doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to reuse a site URL, the original site should be deleted permanently first. To make that this be applied to all the Google Servers could take a while, so wait few hours, better, one or two days.

It's worth to say that Google Sites allow to have multiple owners, so it's not neccessary to delete a site when it was created with the wrong account, instead just add the right account as owner.

From [Share your site with other people - Sites Help](https://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97934)

> Anyone you set to Is owner can change the look and feel of the site as well as make administrative changes, such as deleting the site or adding new owners.